# Multiple Google Maps InfoWindows with deferred content

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, infowindow

I'm having some trouble handling the content of multiple Google Maps (JS API v3) InfoWindows one-by-one attached to multiple markers.

The problem seems to be linked to the fact that I'm delaying the opening of an InfoWindow up to the moment when I'm done retreiving its content from the server which will eventually populate it.

The result is that, upon closing that one InfoWindow and reopening it, it gets re-drawn as many times as I've clicked on its marker.

**An example before showing the code:**

once GMaps is correctly initialized and the markers are set, I click on one of them and its related InfoWindow appears.

Then I close it.

I click on the same marker and two overlapping InfoWindows appear (or maybe it's one, but opened twice).

Then I close it (and the supposedly two InfoWindows close).

And so on and so forth.
Here's the **code**:

```
 var pins = {
     list: [], // where the markers objects are stored.
     window: new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                 content: "Loading..." // promised content
             }),
     draw: function(coords, content_id, timeout) {
               setTimeout(function() {
                   pins.list.push(new google.maps.Marker({
                       position: coords,
                       map: map, // initialized elsewhere
                       title: content_id
                   });
               });
           },
     drop: function(array_of_pins) { // array of objects, each one containing
                                     // "coords" and "content_id" respectively
                                     // of the marker and the InfoWindow.
                var timeout = 100;

                for (i in pins.list) // Loop added to solve the problem
                    google.maps.event.clearListeners(pins.list[i], "click");

                for (i in array_of_pins)
                     pins.draw( array_of_pins[i].coords,
                                array_of_pins[i].content_id, 
                                i * timeout );

                setTimeout(function() {
                    for (i in pins.list) 
                         google.maps.event.addListener(
                             pins.list[i],
                             "click",
                             function() { 
                                 pins.content(this, this.title);
                             }
                         );
                }, array_of_pins.length * timeout);
           },
     content: function(marker, content_id) {
               deferredContentFunction(content_id)
                       .done(function(data) {
                           var content = '<p>'+data.content+'</p>';
                           pins.window.setContent(content);
                           pins.window.open(map, marker);
                       })
                       .fail(function() {
                           // error handling
                       });
           }
 };
```

I suspect the reference (through `this`) to the related marker in the `pins.drop()` function is lost at some point, which in turn causes the problem.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding the click listener to the marker multiple times (once each time you call `drop` on the array of pins).

One option is to clear the listeners before adding them again:

```
for (i in pins.list) 
  google.maps.event.clearListeners(pins.list[i], "click");
  google.maps.event.addListener(
    pins.list[i],
    "click",
    function() { 
      pins.content(this, this.title);
    }
  );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's what I should have been after. Stupid meh. A simple `google.maps.event.clearListeners(pins.list[i], "click")`, for `i` cycling over the `pins.list` array did the job, right before the loop which adds the listeners in the `pins.drop()` function.